# I can´t figure out why my function is returning after first interaction

Tags: python, loops, for-loop

I have the following function but it is returning only the first `for` interaction. And I am stuck on this

```
def window_input(window_length: int, data: pd.DataFrame) -> pd.DataFrame:
      appended_data3 = []
      df = df_per_station.copy()
      for cols in columns_to_shift:
        i = 1
        while i < window_length:
            df[cols + f'x{i}'] = df[cols].shift(-i)
            i = i + 1
            
        if i == window_length:
         df['next_count'] = df['count'].shift(-i)
            
        # Drop rows where there is a NaN
        df = df.dropna(axis=0)
        appended_data3.append(df)
        appended_data3 = pd.concat(appended_data3)
            
        return appended_data3
```

Comment: Fix your indentation for the `return` statement at the end

Comment: When I change the indentation for the return at the end I have the following error while calling the function `new_df = window_input(5, data)`: `TypeError: first argument must be an iterable of pandas objects, you passed an object of type "DataFrame"`

Comment: You are converting the list to a single dataframe, but your `window_input` function wants a list of DataFrames, not a single dataframe.  Remove the `pd.concat` line.